# Does Microsoft fakes framework support c++/unmanaged code

Tags: c++, unit-testing, microsoft-fakes

We are developing unit tests for already existing code in c++. In the recent TechEd heard about Microsoft fakes framework for unit test isolation. But the TechEd video does not show that it is supported for c++ or not. No such this is said on msdn as well. But all examples on msdn is for c# and VB.

Does anyone know if it is supported or not. If not what framework would you recommend for already existing c++ code which is not developed with unit testing in mind.

Comment: this sounds similar to the google mock framework, which does support c++

Comment: Speaking from experience, it's probably better that you <strike>rewrite</strike> refactor it using TDD.  What you're going to go through will be more time.  If you want TDD, do it the right way.

Comment: @Beed our last resort is Google Test Framework, but if fakes frameork supports c++ we wanna go that route.

Comment: As Microsoft keeps declining well-written bug reports for VC++ at MS Connect as "won't fix", C++ is not a target for most of MS's development in VS. It's likely that there's no support for C++.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, finally microsoft responded to the question and the conclusion is, fakes does not support c++/unmanaged code.

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/890349/does-microsoft-fakes-framework-support-c-unmanaged-code